# Method to get the placement of a player with MySQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse-plugin

I`ve a Problem with a SQL Query. I want to develop a Minecraft Plugin. The Plugin contains a Statistic. I want to create a Ranking in the Statistic. The player who have the most kills is on the first place and so on.. I created a Method which calculate your placement. First the SQL Query sort the tabel and than it looks in which your you are.

```
PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM (SELECT @r := @r+1 as pos, kills. * FROM kills, (SELECT @r := 1) tmp ORDER BY Kills DESC) WHERE UUID = ?");
    ps.setString(1, uuid.toString());
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

The Error is: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE UUID = '37bb2c2c-e170-469c-a08e-6a22e7d083cd'' at line 1

I dont know what the Error is.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. Does your table `kills` have a column `kills`?

Comment: are you able execute this query in sql client?

Comment: You will need to use an alias for the inner query and then use the alias for UUID `SELECT * FROM (SELECT @r := @r+1 as pos, kills. * FROM kills, (SELECT @r := 1) tmp ORDER BY Kills DESC) X WHERE X.UUID = ?`

Comment: @Cury What was the solution used? Kindly mark the right solution as answer so others may benefit

Answer (score 0):

You can't use user variables in a JDBC MySQL query.  Here is one workaround for the query:

```
SELECT *,
    1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kills k2 WHERE k2.Kills > k1.Kills) AS pos
FROM kills k1
WHERE UUID = ?
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then analytic functions are a better way to go:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Kills DESC) pos
FROM kills
WHERE UUID = ?
```

You may want to instead use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.  Note that the first correlated subquery approach is technically returning a *rank*, not a row number, in the event that two or more records be tied for the number of kills.